# Opencart Checkout my sql error

Tags: php, mysql, database, paypal, opencart

HI whenever we use bussoc paypal express checkout option.. after enter paypal account login and payment proceed button there appear a msg with mysql server error, Here msg appear wheneven a customer coming back after made payment on paypal

> Notice: error, you have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near order SET customer_id='27' WHERE order_id='279' at line 1
>
> Error no 1064
>
> UPDATE order SET customer_id='27'WHERE order_id='279' in home/public_html/site/system/database/mysql.php line 49
> Here is query. so where it need changes?

```
<?php
final class MySQL {
private $connection;

public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    if (!$this->connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
        exit('Error: Could not make a database connection using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->connection)) {
        exit('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);
    }
    
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->connection);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->connection);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->connection);
    mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE = ''", $this->connection);
}
    
public function query($sql) {
    $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);

    if ($resource) {
        if (is_resource($resource)) {
            $i = 0;
    
            $data = array();
    
            while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                $data[$i] = $result;
    
                $i++;
            }
            
            mysql_free_result($resource);
            
            $query = new stdClass();
            $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
            $query->rows = $data;
            $query->num_rows = $i;
            
            unset($data);

            return $query;  
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->connection) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->connection) . '<br />' . $sql);
        exit();
    }
}

public function escape($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value, $this->connection);
}

public function countAffected() {
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->connection);
}

public function getLastId() {
    return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
}   

public function __destruct() {
    mysql_close($this->connection);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL query has an error. Could you show that query?

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is `order`. That is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You need to escape it with backticks

```
update `order` 
SET customer_id='27' 
WHERE order_id='279'
```

Comment: it'll solve all problem regarding paypal checkout ? and please guide how i can backticks i don't understand thanks for reply

Comment: i face that problem whenever i use checkout process through paypal express with every product in site

Comment: All I can do is tell you the cause of the error and how to fix it. If you have a specific programmers question about paypal express checkout then ask another question about it.

Comment: ok but how i can escape it with backticks pleas suggest. am now at order table in phpmyadmin

Comment: Can you change the SQL query that paypal express is using? Then edit it like in my answer. Or can you tell playpal express what table to use? then change your table name to `orders` instead of `order` for instance.

Comment: i'll change but how i can find that query please

Comment: the query should be in the file `/home/public_html/site/system/database/mysql.php` according to your error output.

Comment: yeah yeah i know it ok can i send you that file please

Comment: You can add the relevant content of that file to you question. It should be around line 49 in that file according to your error output.

Comment: Do you check it where i need to replace code ? or can i remove 49 line code to get rid of this error?

Comment: Unfortunately the query is not defined in that file. Looks like it can't be changed that easily. I recommend writing to the bussoc support hotline to fix that bug.

Comment: ok thanks , i also think about it's bussoc module developer issue

Comment: whenever we made a new order and choose payment method paypal express this show that error which i mention above http://www.tastymaza.com     http://www.ark-sol.com

Answer (score 1):

```
update `oc_order` 
SET customer_id='27' 
WHERE order_id='279'
```

you have add the prefix for the table name.This prefix has been added, when you have installed opencart.

By default it's 'oc_', if you change that then replace it with that